# How to change a 1 line output to multiple lines

Tags: python, string, output

I have this line in a .txt file:

```
I just got home.\nDid you make lunch?\nOh, I see...
```

It's just one line, it's formatted like this for a game, so it is exactly like this, with the \n's.

What I need is that when I print this, after I store it into a variable or list, to print it on multiple lines, respecting the \n. Like this:

```
I just got home.\n
Did you make lunch?\n
Oh, I see...
```

I can't think of a way to modify the output to make a new line after the program displays each \n. How would I do this?

Comment: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: @spectras Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using of `str.replace()` function would be enough:

```
s="I just got home.\nDid you make lunch?\nOh, I see..."
print(s.replace("\n", "\\n\n"))
```

The output:

```
I just got home.\n
Did you make lunch?\n
Oh, I see...
```